# MySQL Select problems

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table #1: **qa_returns_items** [image]

Table #2: **qa_returns_residues**[image]

I have a long time trying to get this Result:

```
item_code -   item_quantity
2         -   1
3         -   2
```

---

IF qa_returns_items.item_code = qa_returns_residues.item_code AND status_code = 11 THEN

> item_quantity = qa_returns_items.item_quantity -
>   qa_returns_residues.item_quantity

ELSEIF qa_returns_items.item_code = qa_returns_residues.item_code AND status_code = 12 THEN

> item_quantity = qa_returns_items.item_quantity +
>   qa_returns_residues.item_quantity

ELSE

```
show diferendes
```

END IF

**I tried this Query:**

```
select  SubQueryAlias.item_code, 
        item_quantity
from    (
        select  
                ri.item_code
        ,       case status_code
                when 11 then ri.item_quantity - rr.item_quantity 
                when 12 then ri.item_quantity + rr.item_quantity
                end as item_quantity
        from    qa_returns_residues rr
        left join    qa_returns_items ri
        on      ri.item_code = rr.item_code
        WHERE ri.returnlog_code = 1
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   item_quantity > 0 GROUP BY (item_code);
```

**The query returns this result:**

```
item_code -   item_quantity
1         -   2
2         -   2
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking???

Comment: Need to select the fields mentioned above, Applying these conditions in columns 4 marked (result)

Comment: I don't understand why you want item codes 2 and 3? What distinguishes them from everything else?

Comment: And I cant find item QUANTITY in the select list!

Comment: Take a look to my query, i replaced some columns with the correct column name

Comment: @Ben it depends the status_code(11,12) will to determine if (addtition/subtraction)

Comment: Your query only handles when `status_code == 11` and `status_code==12`. You need to handle the default case as well.

Comment: as I can do? I have tried in many ways

Comment: Please explain to us what exactly are you trying to achieve with this code and what is it's purpose. You've posted only the structure and the sql result you need but that doesn't make things clear (at least to me)

Comment: @tftd Take a look to pseudo-code, i want to show only 2 rows, the status_code column will to determine if item_quantity will to subtract or add, (11 = subtract | 12 = add) but before need to check if the item_code exist in the another table.

Comment: Your query doesn't return any results. I've created the two tables you've posted in your question and populated the same data. Are you sure the SQL query you've posted returns the data from the image?

Comment: @tftd Yea please look this, http://i48.tinypic.com/2ztj7ty.jpg

Comment: @tftd this is the complete database http://pastebin.com/DKrHiebK

Comment: Why do you have repeating records in the `qa_returns_items` tables? The `returnlog_code` is set to "AUTOINCREMENT" but some of your records have the same `returnlog_code`?

Comment: The AUTOINCREMENT is accidentally in the table qa_returns_items

Comment: ALTER TABLE qa_returns_items CHANGE returnlog_code returnlog_code int(11) NOT NULL;

Comment: Can you give your desired output with test data?

Comment: The table qa_returns_residues: are the residuals of the returns made, the qa_returns_items: are all items that have the return. What I try to do with this query is to obtain the original invoice items has not returns, adding residues to the first return. This is the complete Database: http://pastebin.com/DKrHiebK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem:

```
SELECT  
        item_code, 
        item_quantity, 
        item_unitprice, 
        item_subtotal, 
        item_discount, 
        item_total 
FROM (
        SELECT  qa_returns_items.item_code, 
                qa_returns_items.item_quantity, 
                qa_returns_items.item_unitprice, 
                qa_returns_items.item_subtotal, 
                qa_returns_items.item_discount, 
                qa_returns_items.item_total 
        FROM qa_returns_items 
        WHERE returnlog_code = 1
    UNION
        SELECT  qa_returns_residues.item_code, 
                qa_returns_residues.item_quantity, 
                qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice, 
                qa_returns_residues.item_subtotal, 
                qa_returns_residues.item_discount, 
                qa_returns_residues.item_total 
        FROM qa_returns_residues 
        WHERE returnlog_code = 1 
        ORDER BY item_code ASC
) 
AS SubQueryAlias
WHERE item_code NOT IN (
                        SELECT a.item_code 
                        FROM qa_returns_items a 
                        JOIN qa_returns_residues b 
                            ON b.item_code = a.item_code 
                        WHERE a.returnlog_code = 1 
                            AND b.returnlog_code = 1
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. I havn't tested it. It is very difficult what you require. But I have built it from table structure and given condition clause.

```
select qa_returns_items.item_code, 
       (CASE status_code
         WHEN 11 THEN (qa_returns_items.item_quantity - qa_returns_residues.item_quantity) 
         WHEN 12 THEN (qa_returns_items.item_quantity + qa_returns_residues.item_quantity)   END) as item_quantity , 
        qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice,
       ( qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice * item_quant) as item_subtotal,
       (qa_returns_residues.item_discount * item_quantity) as item_discount,
       ( ( qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice * item_quant) -   
         (qa_returns_residues.item_discount * item_quantity) ) as item_total
where
 item_quantity > 0 AND  qa_returns_items.item_code = qa_returns_residues.item_code
```

**Update:**

```
select qa_returns_items.item_code, 
           (CASE status_code
             WHEN 11 THEN (qa_returns_items.item_quantity - qa_returns_residues.item_quantity) 
             WHEN 12 THEN (qa_returns_items.item_quantity + qa_returns_residues.item_quantity)   END) as item_quant , 
            qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice,
           ( qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice * item_quant) as item_subtotal,
           (qa_returns_residues.item_discount * item_quantity) as item_discount,
           ( ( qa_returns_residues.item_unitprice * item_quant) -   
             (qa_returns_residues.item_discount * item_quantity) ) as item_total
    where
    (CASE status_code
             WHEN 11 THEN (qa_returns_items.item_quantity - qa_returns_residues.item_quantity) 
             WHEN 12 THEN (qa_returns_items.item_quantity + qa_returns_residues.item_quantity)   END) item_quant  > 0 AND  qa_returns_items.item_code = qa_returns_residues.item_code
```

Comment: Your query is right but the column item_quant does not exist replace it to (item_quantity), and add the FROM clause (from qa_returns_items, qa_returns_residues). remember the item_quantity are ambiguous because is on both of tables, this column are the result of the subtraction/addition: qa_returns_items.item_quantity - qa_returns_residues.item_quantity

Comment: That's why I made alias item_quant.

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'item_quant' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I would advice you to start over with a fresh database, no records and start debugging step by step.

First create the database and the tables. After that insert only 2 records with simple data. Afterwards start debugging.

From what I was able to debug the problem is in your sub-select. In the topic you want to see `item_code 2 and 3`. That can't happen because:

```
SELECT ri.item_code,
       CASE status_code
       WHEN 11 then ri.item_quantity - rr.item_quantity 
       WHEN 12 then ri.item_quantity + rr.item_quantity
       END AS item_quantity
FROM      qa_returns_residues rr
LEFT JOIN qa_returns_items ri
ON        ri.item_code = rr.item_code
WHERE     ri.returnlog_code = 1   // Why do you need this for ?
```

returns

```
item_code   item_quantity
2           2
1           0
1           0
1           0
1           2
```

And then the main query selects only the results which have `item_quantity > 0`. 
Thus you get only

```
item_code   item_quantity
1           2
2           2
```

as a result.

I'm not quite sure what's the purpose of this operation but have in mind that *simple* solutions are **always** best!

Comment: The table qa_returns_residues: are the residuals of the returns made, the qa_returns_items: are all items that have the return. What I try to do with this query is to obtain the original invoice items has not returns, adding residues to the first return.